# Rubik's cube solver (help required for hardware)

Tags: microcontroller, c, hardware

I am very new to this. I have only done a "introduction to programming" course where I learnt C. I once worked with arduino. My program in C language prints the solution of the given rubik's cube combination on the screen. Now I want to make hardware for it and I have to use 6 stepper motors for 6 faces.

**MY QUESTIONS**

1)Is there a platform such as arduino which can accommodate 6 stepper motors.

2) Do I need 6 drivers for 6 stepper motors

3)which stepper motors should I use?

4)what is estimate costs for that?

Comment: Please read http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: how is the motors attached to the rubik cube faces ?? is it built internally ? are you trying to make a custom made one ? how is the human able to scramble after ??

Comment: Please don't edit the question to the extent that it makes the existing answers invalid.

Comment: A robotic cube solver is apparently a project that has been done originally one or more times, and cloned many, many more times.  You might as well spend some time researching what others have done rather than asking unresearched "reimplement from scratch" questions here, which are outside the mission of this site anyway.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for the advice but I just wanted to do it myself. I am a first year mechanical engineering student with interest in programming. You learn more when you struggle,right? Can you refer me to a good source (or possibly a online academic source) where I can learn more about hardware programming. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to "do it yourself" then you should do research rather than asking people here to solve the problem for you.  Research would include looking at what others have used to solve this problem, or, if you specifically want to avoid that to preserve originality, then looking at what has been used for *similar* problems.  This isn't a "hardware programming" problem, or at least it *cannot* be one until the *mechanical* and *sensor* problems are well under control.

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Is there a platform such as arduino which can accommodate 6 stepper motors.

Yes. Each motor driver will require one pulse signal and one direction signal. You will need 12 outputs.

> 2) Do I need 6 drivers for 6 stepper motors

Yes.

> 3) Which stepper motors should I use?

That's a product recommendation question and is off-topic.

> 4) What is estimate costs for that?

That's your job!

Comment: Thanks for replying! 3) I actually meant unipolar or bipolar stepper motor.

Comment: also 4) pretty impossible to tell without knowing what kind of expenses you'd have to make to get the equipment you need to solve the thing.

Comment: @JaskiratSinghUbhi uni/bipolar depends on what you'd prefer to work with, really. This is like "I need to build a car. Should I use these or the other ignition fuses?"; we can't tell you at this state of your project. These are all very interesting design choices, but you must first investigate on your own. There's no general rule.

Comment: I am sorry for 4th question. I am removing it now.

Comment: Can I also use raspberry pi instead of arduino? In my original code, the rubik's cube is defined in a 2-d array. everything the program does is interchanging entries in that 2-d array. All the cube rotations are defined by functions. For example right( input[6][9]);  means rotating right side 90 degrees. when this function is used, it interchange couple of entries on the 2-d array and print "right" on the screen. All I need to do is to include a line of code in this function that rotates the stepper motor(on right side) by 90 degrees clockwise. This might help you to give me some advise.

Comment: @JaskiratSinghUbhi you can use anything from an 8-pin microcontroller to a Connection Machine to do the task.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I think things like 8-pin microcontroller are hard to program for me with no experience in hardware programming whereas platforms like arduino have rich libraries. I have no idea about raspberry pi. Does it also have a compiling software and library similar to arduino?

Comment: @JaskiratSinghUbhi -- if you have no idea what a Raspberry Pi does, then why are you asking about using it?  Due diligence suggests that you should spend a few minutes reading about it before asking.